# how to remove selected Apppools in IIS with powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am using the following comment to remove a single web application pool:

```
Remove-WebAppPool Apppool1
```

But I want to remove multiple selected Apppools.  I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
Remove-WebAppPool Apppool1,Apppool2
```

Comment: Since `-Name` does not support an array of names, you need to loop through them --> `'Apppool1','Apppool2' | Foreach-Object { Remove-WebAppPool -Name $_ }`

Comment: Is your issue solved?If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the below Powershell script:

```
#Set New line using OFS special Powershell variable
$OFS = "`n"
#Externally set input value as string
[string[]] $_ServerList= @()
#Get the input from the user
$_ServerList = READ-HOST "Enter List of Servers"
#splitting the list of input as array by Comma & Empty Space

$_ServerList = $_ServerList.Split(',').Split(' ')


ForEach ($ApplicationPool in $_ServerList)
{
Remove-WebAppPool $ApplicationPool
}
```

[image]